# Factoring many columns at once

Tags: r

I'm struggling with a datset from a survey. I have about 80 columns of preferences, categorized as follows:

> "Extremely unattractive1","2","3","4","Neither
>   5","6","7","8","Extremely attractive9"

and I'd like to factor them into numbers from 1 to 9.
Usually, I use

```
df$c<-factor(df$c, levels="...", labels="...")
```

but it doesn't seem to work for this case.
I also tried creating a new dataset with the columns of interest and then applying lapply

```
ds<-survey[,c(7:10)]
survey[ds]<-lapply(survey[ds],factor(levels = c("Extremely unattractive1","Extremely attractive9"),labels=c("1","9")))
```

But it doesn't work either
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! Can you share a reproducible sample using dput(head(df))? Refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to know how to get a reproducible sample. BTW, did you check the str of df$c?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm at my very first steps with rstudio so I don't really know how to write a reproducible sample. I checked the string and it's correct, because if I apply it to a single column it works, it doesn't work when I apply it to many columns

Comment: Try `df[ds] <- lapply(df[ds], function(i)factor(i, levels = ...))`

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by "i"? Sorry but I don't understand

Comment: It's not a matter of formatting them one by one because that works, I can't make it work for the whole dataset at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your data frame is named survey an you want to change columns 7 to 10 to factors.

```
survey[7:10] <-lapply(survey[7:10], 
                      function(x) 
                        factor(x, levels = c("Extremely unattractive1","2","3","4","Neither 5","6","7","8","Extremely attractive9"),
                                          labels=c(1:9)))
```